# How to send ESC/POS commands on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, phonegap-plugins, escpos

I am programming a Phonegap App that sends printing to a thermal printer using Bluetooth

I am using [phonegap-bluetooth-plugin](https://github.com/tanelih/phonegap-bluetooth-plugin) and print normally

But when using ESC commands, they are being printed with the text.

I can print using the code:

```
bluetooth.write(onSuccess, onFailure, "Hi Dani, How are You?");
```

I do not know how I should include the ESC commands in this code... 
Ex. Trying to select the size of the characters

```
var data_print = "1D 21 02"+"Hi Dani, How are You?";
bluetooth.write(onSuccess, onFailure, data_print);
```

As would be the correct way to insert the ESC commands in this code?
Any feedback is appreciated!
Tks !